# How can I align a ImageView to the right edge of a Button?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, alignment

I've created a simple Layout with a Button, a TextView and a ImageView(with a questionmark in it).

```
<Button
        android:background="#f00"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewmas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:text="title "
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/questionmark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewmas"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewmas"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/questionmark"/>
```

[image]

[The question mark should be a bit more right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jNgr.png)

I want the image's right edge(questionmark) to align at the right edge of the button.
Additional the top and bottom should align at the top and bottom of the title's textView(same height).

Why don't the image align at the right edge, but but a bit more left?
I noticed that if I increase the title textsize(e.g. 30dp) the problem dissapears, but I need a small textsize.

------EDIT: Is there perhaps a minimum size for images, under which the statements doesn't work well?

Comment: What u exactly wants can u make an image in paint if u wants to then I will design for u exactly u want.

Comment: Make sure your image does not have any extra padding around. If there is any extra padding with the image, remove it using photoshop or any other tool. Alternatively, check with this image and see whether it fits or not .

https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/78/78299.png

Comment: I've posted a solution. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:scaleType="fitEnd"` to your `ImageView`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:text="Button"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewmas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:text="title "
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/questionmark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewmas"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewmas"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

**Explanation**

This is how the `ImageView` would appear without the `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewmas"` attribute

[image]

When you add the `layout_alignTop` attribute to the `ImageView`, it is squeezed down to the height of the `TextView` and the image it contains is scaled down. By default, the `scaleType` property of the `ImageView` appears to be `centerInside`; which scales down the image and aligns it to the center of the image view, thereby adding some space to the left and right.

The solution would be to use `android:scaleType="fitEnd"` to move the scaled down image to the end of the image view

**The output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
```

or:

```
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
```

and then you can add some margin from left.

Comment: both of your alignment statements I already added in my code. Margin left changes nothing.

Comment: Then you can get your text's height and set it to your images height and height.